# Avoid Google Analytics Sampling (Date Handling Functions, Query Partitioning & Automation)

Tags: python, api, google-analytics

I'm able to successfully connect to Google Analytics API using Python on Jupyter Notebook, however. If I select too wide a date range I will most definitely get sampled data. If I select too narrow a date range, I will have to reset the dates, manually run my code over and over again and merge multiple CSVs. I need data from at least 2-3 years worth of data.

I think the best way to do it is to partition the query and programmatically loop through the desired timeframe, aggregating the report back together once done. This way, when you pull the report, it will appear as if making one query but in reality it’s making the number of queries behind the scenes, based on how you configure granularly you define the query partitioning.

I also need a way to automatically run this API code to get fresh data daily or weekly and saved on a CSV.

Can anyone help me add to my existing code a way to break down queries (add a time handling function) and keep duplicating?

```
# Setup Variables
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"]
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = "client_secrets.json"
VIEW_ID = "12345678"

# Initializes & Authorizes Google Analytics Reporting API v4 Service Object
def initialize_analyticsreporting():
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)
    analytics = build("analyticsreporting", "v4", credentials=credentials)
    return analytics

# Queries the Google Analytics Reporting API & Returns the Response
def get_report(analytics):
    return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        "reportRequests": [
        {
          "viewId": VIEW_ID,
          "dateRanges": [{"startDate": "2017-01-01", "endDate": "2020-10-30"}],
          "metrics": [{"expression": "ga:avgTimeOnPage", "alias": "Avg. Time on Page"},
                      {"expression": "ga:pageviewsPerSession", "alias": "Pages / Session"},
                      {"expression": "ga:pageviews","alias": "Pageviews"},
                      {"expression": "ga:uniquePageviews", "alias": "Unique Pageviews"},
                      {"expression": "ga:avgSessionDuration", "alias": "Avg. Session Duration"},
                      {"expression": "ga:bounceRate", "alias": "Bounce Rate"},
                      {"expression": "ga:sessions", "alias": "Sessions"},
                      {"expression": "ga:users", "alias": "Users"}],
          'dimensions': [{"name": "ga:campaign"},
                         {"name": "ga:medium"},
                         {"name": "ga:source"},
                         {"name": "ga:userType"},
                         {"name": "ga:date"},
                         {"name": "ga:pagePath"}],
            "samplingLevel": "LARGE",

        }]
      }
  ).execute()

response = get_report(initialize_analyticsreporting())
print(response)


# Parses & Prints Google Analytics Reporting API Response
def print_response(response):
    list = []
    for report in response.get("reports", []):
        columnHeader = report.get("columnHeader", {})
        dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get("dimensions", [])
        metricHeaders = columnHeader.get("metricHeader", {}).get("metricHeaderEntries", [])
        rows = report.get("data", {}).get("rows", [])
        for row in rows:
            dict = {}
            dimensions = row.get("dimensions", [])
            dateRangeValues = row.get("metrics", [])
            for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
                dict[header] = dimension
            for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
                for metric, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get("values")):
                    if "," in value or "." in value:
                        dict[metric.get("name")] = float(value)
                    else:
                        dict[metric.get("name")] = int(value)
            list.append(dict)
        df = pd.DataFrame(list)
        return df

# Create a Pandas DataFrame With Google Analytics Data
ga_df = pd.DataFrame(print_response(response))
ga_df = ga_df.rename(
    columns={"ga:campaign": "Campaign",
             "ga:date": "Date",
             "ga:medium": "Medium",
             "ga:pagePath": "Page",
             "ga:source": "Source",
             "ga:userType": "User Type",
            })
ga_df.head()
ga_df

# Export to CSV
ga_df.to_csv("savedReport.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no dedicated function, you could build it by checking the value of `samplesReadCounts` and `samplingSpaceSizes` (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics#sampling) in the response at each call, and in case of sampling, provide a new call with a reduced interval implementing **Exponential Backoff** to avoid error of quota (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/errors#backoff).